# AWS, terraform) How to connect to new instance from another instance which created new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, key-pair

I cannot connect to **instance2** from **instance1**, which creates instance2 by terraform, because instance1 has no key_name.pem, except key_name.pub.

**How can I download key_name.pem to the instance1?**

Here is what I did:

1. I created AWS instance 1
2. generate ssh key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "roy" -f "$HOME/.ssh/test_key" -N ""
```

3. terraform apply(key resource)

```
# main.tf
provider "aws"{
    region = "ap-northeast-2"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "test_key" {
key_name = "test_key"
public_key = "${file("~/.ssh/test_key.pub")}"
}
```

4. terraform apply(create instance)

```
provider "aws"{
    region = "ap-northeast-2"
}
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
ami = "ami-06e7b9c5e0c4dd014"
instance_type = "t2.nano"
key_name = "test_key"
tags {
Name = "ec2_instance"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_data` when creating **instance1**.
This can be a regular bash script, in which you create the `id_rsa` (**key_name.pem**) file for the user `ubuntu` (if you are using an Ubuntu AMI).

```
#!/bin/bash

#create id_rsa

echo "[KEY_DATA]" > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But why do you even need a private key on the instance?
Terraform does not need the private key...

Just in case you are using **instance1** as SSH bastion:
You should use SSH forwarding instead of copying your private key to an instance: Run `ssh -A instance1_ip` and then `ssh instance2_ip` from instance one. This way you don't need a private key on **instance1**.

Comment: I tried this command without private key: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/test_key ubuntu@instanc2_public_ip`. But it didn't work, no response, I don't know what I did wrong. So I wanna try using private key in my bastion instance1, like aws said: `ssh -i "test_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-~ip~.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: But instance2 has a security group attached which allows incomming SSH traffic?